# android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttServiceBinder

Tags: java, android, service, casting, mqtt

I'm working on an app that includes a chat feature using the MqttAndroidClient and I have been having an issue initializing the client.

What I'm trying to achieve is to run a seperate process(using *:remote*) to run the mqtt client to subscribe to the broker in order to fetch the messages from my chat server.
The remote service is created within the Main Activity and I've set the IPC using an AIDL.
I know that the error code points out that there is an error with the IPC; however, I can't seem to find the reason why, because I'm pretty sure I've set the AIDL correctly.

Long story short, here is my service codes:

```
private static final String MQTT_BROKER = "________(blank on purpose)";
private String userId;
private String publishTopic;
private String subscribeTopic;
MqttAndroidClient client;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return new Chat_AIDL.Stub() {
        @Override
        public String passString(String message) throws RemoteException {
            return message;
        }
    };
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    userId = intent.getStringExtra("userId");
    publishTopic = "chat/+/" + userId + "/";
    subscribeTopic = "chat/#/" + userId + "/";

    Log.d("publishTopic", publishTopic);
    Log.d("subscribeTopic", subscribeTopic);


    establishMqttConnection();

    client.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {

        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage receivedMessage) throws Exception {
            Intent in = new Intent();
            String msg = new String(receivedMessage.getPayload(), "UTF-8");

            in.putExtra("resultCode", Activity.RESULT_OK);
            in.putExtra("chatMsg", msg);
            Log.d("MQTT_RECEIVED", msg);
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getBaseContext()).sendBroadcast(in);
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {

        }
    });


    Log.d("SERVICE_CHAT", "STICKY");

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}

private void establishMqttConnection() {
    MemoryPersistence memPer = new MemoryPersistence();
    client = new MqttAndroidClient(this, MQTT_BROKER, userId, memPer);
    try {
        client.connect(null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                Log.d("MQTT", "SUCCESS");
                subscribeMessage();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                Log.d("MQTT", "FAILURE");
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void subscribeMessage() {
    try {
        client.subscribe(subscribeTopic, 0, null, new IMqttActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {

            }
        });
    } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MqttException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same question, and I found that I can not deal with the remote service like a local service, see this [issue](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android/issues/110). When the mqtt service is created in a different processes, the official example way will not work.

My way to solve this question is creating my own service and make this service created in the same processes with the mqtt service :

```
<application>
    <!-- skipped... -->
    <service
        android:name=".MyService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:process=":background" />
    <service  
        android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService"
        android:process=":background" />
</application>
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Yeah @l-swifter sticking the MqttService to the existing parent process worked, since I already have a dedicated service that run on it's own process to communicate and do other things.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem because in our code we have two services: one for MQTT and another one which synchronizes things with server.

We tried to put in separate processes but it didn't work. Also we tried to put them in same process, but it didn't work too.

After looking for solutions, as it was a simple ClassCastException we decided to download source code of paho.mqtt.android and check for that casting.

So, the steps we made:

- Clone repository from here: [Eclipse Paho MQTT Android](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.android)
- Import the project on your IDE (i.e. Android Studio)
- In `MqttAndroidClient` class of package `org.eclipse.paho.android.service` modify this method and put it like here:

  ```
  @Override
      public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder binder) {
          if (MqttServiceBinder.class.isAssignableFrom(binder.getClass())) {
              mqttService = ((MqttServiceBinder) binder).getService();
              bindedService = true;
              // now that we have the service available, we can actually
              // connect...
              doConnect();
          }
      }
  ```
- Compile and make the module `paho.mqtt.android.service'`and use the aar generated by your IDE.

With that aar we have no problems and the issue has gone away.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That error hurt my brain. Thanks for that solution, works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this exception today, I did alot of changes but most of them were breaking my code and its logic. This is my logic, I have an app (says the client) which is sending data to another app (says the server). To get that done, followed up [this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130731024012/http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/InterAppCommunication). I had to do some modifications in the my `AndroidManifest.xml` of the servers which are

```
<service android:name=".service.RemoteService"
        android:process=":remote">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="full.package.name.service.RemoteService" >
            </action>
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

As @L. Swifter says, the issue is because we are trying to connected to MQTT from a service that is meant for `remote listening`.

To address this issue, I can out with this workaround.

1. Create another service RemoteServiceForMqtt
2. In the service RemoteService, starts the service RemoteServiceForMqtt
3. While starting the service add the data that you want to send to Mqtt as extras.
4. In RemoteServiceForMqtt, override the method `public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` where you add your method which will send data to mqtt.

That is

```
public class RemoteServiceForMqtt extends Service
{
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MqttClientUtil.getInstance(RemoteServiceForMqtt.this).reconnect(); // MqttClientUtil is a class that content all the necessary informations needed to connect to mqtt
        if (intent != null){
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            sendToMQTT(bundle.getString("data1"),bundle.getString("data2"),bundle.getString("data3"));
        }
        return 0b1;
    }


    public void sendToMQTT(String data1, String data2,String data3) {

        JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
        try {
            object.put("data1", data1);
            object.put("data2", data2);
            object.put("data3", data3);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MqttClientUtil.getInstance( RemoteServiceForMqtt.this).publish(object.toString());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Add `<service android:name=".service.RemoteServiceForMqtt"/>` in `AndroidManifest.xml` of server.

In RemoteService (where the exception occurs) replace with

```
Intent service = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RemoteServiceForMqtt.class);
service.putExtra("data1","data1");
service.putExtra("data2","data2");
service.putExtra("data3","data3");
startService(service);
```

Hope this helps someone.